# using pushViewController in containerView Not work

Tags: swift, pushviewcontroller, uicontainerview, presentviewcontroller

I have created containerView which contain tableViewController.
The main issue, when user click on information, tableViewController must show the information which user clicked.

it show the information when I use `present(<#T##UIViewController#>, animated: <#T##Bool#>, completion: <#T##(() -> Void)?#>)`
but doesnt work if I call `self.navigationController?.pushViewController`

the main issue is when I make `vc.info = info` it doesnt work, the info has value but using injection the value in another class is nil.

Here is my code:

```
func showLoginDetailsOnIpad(encryptedDataBase: info) {

    self.view.addSubview(loginContainer)
    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard?
    mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardiPad", bundle: nil)

    let vc = mainStoryboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tableVC") as! tableVC
    vc.info = info
    vc.showingLoginInfo = true
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: The container view should contain a UINavigationController. The `tableViewController` should be the root view controller of the UINavigationController. Then calling `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explanation

You mentioned the use of a containerView. The table controller being displayed inside the containerView, doesn't automatically get a reference to the nearest `navigationController`.

So in this line: `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

`self.navigationController` might actually be `nil`. You can confirm this by printing its value before running the push method like so:

```swift
print(self.navigationController) // See if this prints nil.
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

#### Fixes

To fix the issue, I suggest to pass a reference to the parent controller's `navigationController` to the child controller - through the embed segue.

In your parent controller, you can use this code:

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? UITableViewController{
        destination.navigationController = self.navigationController
    }
}
```

And in your table view controller, leave the code as is.